# How to implement automatic reloading of the python aiogram bot?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, reboot, aiogram

I am creating a telegram bot in python using aiogram. I want to prescribe a condition under which the bot will reboot. Tell me how to implement using the code to restart the bot on aiogram? Thank you in advance for your help!

The bot works on a VPS with Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create your own service by creating file in /lib/systemd/system folder.
For example:

```
/lib/systemd/system/myBot.service
```

Assuming your bot is in /opt/myBot/ folder - put the following lines into that file:

```
[Unit]
Description=myBot - Telegram bot
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/mybot/myBot.py
WorkingDirectory=/opt/mybot/
KillMode=process
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Save the file and enable service:

```
systemctl enable myBbot
```

Now - start the service

```
systemctl start myBot
```

To check status

```
systemctl status myBot
```

To stop bot

```
systemctl stop myBot
```

If you happen to edit the service file - reload it by issuing

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```